# Word for saying something knowing it's not true

Tags: single-word-requests

I was just talking on the phone to my old boss who was on his way in to my work to fill out paperwork he needs to sort. I asked him, "*Would you like me to put the kettle on*?", to which he said, "*You no longer need to toady to me*" (joking of course). I laughed and said, "*Sure, you know that I never did*".

He's convinced that there is one word to describe this kind of thing. But neither one of us can think of what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than "lying"? What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: Banter? 'This kind of thing' isn't very specific.

Answer (score 6):

You might be looking for the word "facetious".

> **fa·ce·tious**
>       adjective
>       1. not meant to be taken seriously or literally: *a facetious remark*.
>       2. amusing; humorous.
>       3. lacking serious intent; concerned with something nonessential, amusing,
>          or frivolous: *a facetious person*.

from [reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facetious)

Answer (score 4):

As J.R. says, one could describe OP's offer to put the kettle on as *sarcasm*, but generally that word has significant negative overtones, so I don't really think it's suitable in this context.

OP is simply indulging in [banter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banter) - addressing his boss in a witty and teasing manner. He's being *waggish, whimsical, wisecracking,* etc. - there'll be hundreds of similar words and expressions.

But if someone said to OP (after he put the phone down) *"Why did you say you'll put the kettle on? We don't even **have** a kettle in this office!"*, I think the most likely response would be...

> *"I was **only joking**."*

Comment: +1'd for 'banter'-- I think that's the most appropriate word for this kind of thing (in noun form, at least).  'Teasing' is a good alternative in verb form.

Comment: Side note: I agree that _sarcasm_ has some possible negative overtones (and duly noted that in my answer), but, in the context of one admitting, "I was just being sarcastic," I think that negativity is siginficantly diminished. In my part of the U.S., anyway, I'd be more likely to hear one say, "I was only being sarcastic" than something like, "It was only banter." P.S. I think the best part of this answer is "wisecraking, etc. - there'll be hundreds of similar words..."

Comment: @J.R.: *Wisecracking* is 100% American (you'd virtually *never* hear it in the UK). I must admit that until just now, I thought it was hopelessly dated wartime slang, but apparently it's been [steadily making a comeback over recent decades](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wisecracking&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: I was more complimenting the 'many similar words' part; it is indeed as you say - there are [many ways to say it](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wisecracking%2Cwisecracker%2Cwiseacre%2Cwise+guy%2Cwising+off%2Cclowning+around&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3)

Comment: @J.R.: Yeah - I just chose those three because they all started with the same letter (a feeble attempt to imply there might be at least another three for every other first letter! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **leg-pull** - your boss was just *pulling your leg* while knowing well that there was no kettle.

> **Leg-pull**
>
> "A good-humoured hoax, bluff or practical joke" (Chambers)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *badinage*. [Compact Oxford English Dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/badinage?view=uk) defines it as

> humorous or witty conversation: *he developed a nice line in badinage with the Labour leader*

Similarly, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/badinage)

> playful or frivolous repartee or banter

And [Wordsmyth](http://www.wordsmyth.net/?ent=badinage)

> playful conversation marked by joking or teasing; banter.

Comment: I think _badinage_ is a great fit, but it should be noted that many people wouldn't know what that word means. +1 for expanding my vocabulary, though.

Comment: @J.R. If many people knowing the meaning of a word were the criterion for our repartee on this site, lots of our words would go down.

Comment: I just thought it was worth noting the word's rarity. (I wouldn't want a non-native speaker to read your answer, and start using that word a lot, expecting that most people will know what it means.)

Comment: @J.R. I though our goal was the aggrandisement of esoterica, if only to ensure that native speakers, as well as non-native speakers, will hold us in awe.

Answer (score 1):

Were you two being *sarcastic* with each other?

Part of [Macmillan's](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sarcasm) definition says that *sarcasm* is *saying or writing the opposite of what you mean*.

Sometimes sarcasm can refer to more biting remarks, or more caustic humor.  But it can be used in the more lighthearted sense that you mention:

> **Ned:** Were you really going to put a tea kettle on for me?
> **Ted:** No, I was just being sarcastic.

Comment: I think *verbal irony* is a better fit than *sarcasm*. (People do use *sarcasm* in the way you describe, but I'd consider it wrong or colloquial, like using *passive voice* in reference to a sentence like "Mistakes occurred".)

Comment: @ruakh: That's a really good point; I've described a more informal, conversational use of the word. (If people who uttered that phrase consulted a dictionary beforehand, they might scramble to find a better way of saying it, upon realizing that they were about to use a word that's, strictly speaking, so closely aligned with _scorn_ and _ridicule_.)